# How to check all input fields that, are they empty or not

Tags: php

I want to use single line code to check all input fields to find out are they empty or not.

I tried checking each input field one by one but its too much time taking.

```
$name = $_POST['commenterName'];
$email = $_POST['commenterEmail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$blogNo = $row['blogNo'];

if($name='' AND $email='' AND $message='') {
  $comment_error = "Please fill all required fields.";
}
```

I need something like this.

```
if($name='' AND $email='' AND $message='') {
      $comment_error = "Please fill all required fields.";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a trick. You could use `array_filter()` function that takes `strlen` as a second parameter. It will apply `strlen()` function to each array element and remove it, if its length is 0. Then you can just compare two arrays:

```
if (count($_POST) != count(array_filter($_POST,'strlen')) {
    $comment_error = "Please fill all required fields.";
}
```